# Getting a blank screen during staging errors in Rails/Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I usually get the typical red error message when errors occur in my staging environment but lately the errors have been resulting in a blank screen.  Is there a way to explicitly tell Rails to raise the typical error message in specific environments?

Answer (score 1):

In your `staging.rb` environment file set `config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local` to `true`.